# how can I redefine the ruby and rails request.ip and request.remote_ip methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I've a rails app and I'm trying to overload the request.remote_ip and request.ip in order to use the cloudflare header (HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP) if it's present...
I've tried these, but none of them work:

```
module Rack
  class Request
    class << self
      def ip
        @ip ||= (@env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] || super)
      end
    end
  end
end

module ActionDispatch
  class Request < Rack::Request
    class << self
      def remote_ip
        @remote_ip ||= (@env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] || super)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I can't use an extra method like

```
def connecting_ip
  @env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] || request.remote_ip
end
```

in the application_controller because I've some other gems (like devise) which use request.ip

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you redefining these methods to point to a header which doesn't typically contain IP address information?

Comment: sorry, my bad (I copy&pasted from the code I was trying to see if it loaded some value)... the correct header value is HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP, which is set on request under cloudflare
I've also tried to remove the class << self, but it returns the error: !! Unexpected error while processing request: super: no superclass method `ip' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000000be78c8>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe `request` is an instance. But you are defining class methods.  Remove the `class << self` nonsense and you instead be redefining instance methods.

Just a note though, this sounds kind of crazy. Be careful in there. Frameworks dont always like having their guts rearranged.

---

Your error message when using instance methods means something else is going on.  `super` calls the superclass implementation. But when you reopen a class and override things, you are literally overwriting the original implementation.  Since the method doesn't exist in the superclass, `super` doesn't work.

Instead you can use `alias` to save the original implementation *before* you declare the new method that would replace it.

```
module ActionDispatch
  class Request < Rack::Request
    alias :remote_ip_orig :remote_ip
    def remote_ip
      @remote_ip ||= (@env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] || remote_ip_orig)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried that too, the problem is when the header value is not present. It throws an error because of "super":
!! Unexpected error while processing request: super: no superclass method `ip' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000000be78c8>

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma between the aliases: `alias :remote_ip_orig :remote_ip`

Answer (score 3):

If you you want to use CloudFlare and detect the true IP like I did without an Ngingx or Apache module, this monkey patching approach is a really bad idea, this will lead to unexpected results in the future.  You'd be much better off using a Middleware as it should be used.  Here is one that I came up with and have implemented.

```ruby
module Rack
  class CloudFlareFixup
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      if env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']
        env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] = env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']
        env['REMOTE_ADDR'] = env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']
      end
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

Simply add this into your application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before(0, Rack::CloudFlareFixup)
```

You can see the complete Gist for this at https://gist.github.com/mattheworiordan/9024372

Comment: Which directory do i put that module in?

Comment: Your middleware should be placed right before `ActionDispatch::RemoteIp` middleware and not in at the top of the rack stack.  

    `use config.middleware.insert_before(ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, Rack::CloudFlareFixup)`  

  That way `use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions` and `ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions` can catch the app route exceptions before before the request is handled by your middleware.

You can read more about  `ActionDispatch::RemoteIp` at rails api:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/RemoteIp.html

Comment: This answer should be updated with a link to his newer gist:
https://gist.github.com/mattheworiordan/9828493

Answer (score 1):

I tried many solutions to this problem.  Here is what I found:

- `cloudflare-rails` gem => this sets both ip and remote_ip to the originating ip.  I wanted ip to represent the cloudflare ip that it came from, and remote_ip to represent the originating ip of the user, so that wouldn't work for me.  It operates by looking up the list of Cloudflare IP ranges every 12 hours and adding those to trusted_proxies.  It then patches: - `ActionDispatch::Request.ip`, `ActionDispatch::Request.remote_ip` and `Rack::Attack::Request.trusted_proxy?` with the cloudflare trusted proxies so that ip and remote_ip ignore them and use the originating ip of the user that initiated the request.
- `actionpack-cloudflare` gem => this is much simpler.  all it does is directly set `ActionDispatch.remote_ip = @env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']` which is in accordance with Cloudflare best recommended best practice, but it didn't seem worth it to use a gem for 1 line of code.
- Hand Rolled

```
# config/initializers/cloudflare.rb

# These values should rarely or never change and Cloudflare should alert us before that happens.
# The list of Cloudflare proxy server ip ranges comes from https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/
CLOUDFLARE_IP_RANGES = [IPAddr.new("103.21.244.0/22"),IPAddr.new("103.22.200.0/22"),IPAddr.new("103.31.4.0/22"),IPAddr.new("104.16.0.0/12"),IPAddr.new("108.162.192.0/18"),IPAddr.new("131.0.72.0/22"),IPAddr.new("141.101.64.0/18"),IPAddr.new("162.158.0.0/15"),IPAddr.new("172.64.0.0/13"),IPAddr.new("173.245.48.0/20"),IPAddr.new("188.114.96.0/20"),IPAddr.new("190.93.240.0/20"),IPAddr.new("197.234.240.0/22"),IPAddr.new("2405:8100::/32"),IPAddr.new("2405:b500::/32"),IPAddr.new("2606:4700::/32"),IPAddr.new("2803:f800::/32"),IPAddr.new("2a06:98c0::/29"),IPAddr.new("2c0f:f248::/32")
]

# By adding the cloudflare IP ranges as trusted_proxies, rails ignores those IPs when setting remote_ip and correctly sets it to the originating IP
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.trusted_proxies = CLOUDFLARE_IP_RANGES + ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::TRUSTED_PROXIES
```

Lastly, I wanted to block non-proxied requests

```
# config/initializers/rack_attack.rb
class Rack::Attack
  class Request < ::Rack::Request
    # Create a remote_ip method for rack request by setting it equal to the cloudflare connecting ip header
    # To restore original visitor IP addresses at your origin web server, Cloudflare recommends your logs or applications
    # look at CF-Connecting-IP instead of X-Forwarded-For since CF-Connecting-IP has a consistent format containing only one IP.
    # https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-CloudFlare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-
    def remote_ip
      @remote_ip ||= (env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] || ip).to_s
    end

    # This checks the request IP against Cloudflare IP ranges and the action dispatch default trusted proxies.
    # These include various local IPs like 127.0.0.1 so that local requests won't be blocked.
    def proxied?
      Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.trusted_proxies.any? { |range| range === ip }
    end
  end

  # Block all requests coming from non-Cloudflare IPs
  blocklist("block non-proxied requests in production") do |req|
    if req.proxied?
      false
    else
      req.log :warn
      true
    end
  end
end
```